# how to count records with value maed by a substring() in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like these one :

```
id | name | sid
---|------|-----
1  | Mary | 123456789
2  | Sean | 34567896874341
3  | Paul | 12345678934782
4  | Guy  | 765432689
5  | Joe  | 98765465321675
```

I need to display the count of rows that have the same substring value : substring (sid,1,9) and this for every rows.

My expected output is :

```
id | name | sub         | count
---|------|-------------|------
1  | Mary |123456789    | 2
2  | Sean |345678968    | 1
3  | Paul |123456789    | 2
4  | Guy  |765432689    | 1
5  | Joe  |987654653    | 1
```

How can I do that with one mysql query.

Thanks.

Comment: "GROUP BY" can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected results imply that you just want to get back the original dataset along with a new column which contains the substring count for each `sid` across the entire table.  In the query below, I compute the `sid` count in a subquery and then join this back to your original table.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name,
       t2.sub,
       t2.sid_count
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(sid, 1, 9) AS sub, COUNT(*) AS sid_count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(sid, 1, 9)
) t2
    ON SUBSTRING(t1.sid, 1, 9) = t2.sub
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query:

```
select name,substring(sid,1,9) as sub,count(*) as count from myTable group by sub;
```